# How do we deal with interdisciplinary questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons, policy

As the borders between various disciplines are slowly vanishing with the advent of interdisciplinary areas like Biophysics, Environmental and climate studies, and Complex systems, how do we deal with such questions in Physics SE? Usually, I try to answer questions that can be reasonably explained with physics. Others I vote to close or ask to migrate to Biology or the sister sites.  But how much exactly is "reasonable" is a matter of debate. I have two concerns that need to be addressed.

1. To what extent can we create new and new interdisciplinary SEs whenever a new field emerges? Would that be sustainable in the long run?
2. What are the real reasons why there should be separate SE sites when the disciplines they address themselves are getting more and more interconnected?

Comment: There is always some grey in interdisciplinary areas. Furthermore each site here may define the edges differently. But note that astronomy questions exist just fine on Physics even though there is a (broader) Astronomy site. Just like the Journal of Physical Chemistry and the Journal of Chemical Physics have co-existed for a long long time.

Comment: I feel like this question has been touched upon several times over the last many years, but I cannot (easily?) find an example.